# 'Error: Cannot assign [undefined] to QString' in FolderListModel on Component.onCompleted in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

```
ScrollView
{
    id: scrollViewHead
    height: 400; width: 400
    frameVisible: true

    Image
    {
        id: currentPicture
        height: 400; width: 400
        source: folderModel.fetchCurrentFileName
        z:0
    }
}

FolderListModel
{
    id: folderModel
    nameFilters: ["*.png"]

    folder: "file:///home/eeee/template"

    property int    fetchIndex: -1
    property string fetchCurrentFileName

    onFetchIndexChanged:
    {
        fetchCurrentFileName = get (fetchIndex, "fileName")
    }
}

Component.onCompleted: folderModel.fetchIndex = 0
```

---

This results in:

`Error: Cannot assign [undefined] to QString` on the line which has the `get` method.

The problem is that this code works fine when I click next button (which I have not shown here). That button increments `folderModel.fetchIndex`.

But when I increment `folderModel.fetchIndex` through `Component.onCompleted:` that error gets shown.

P.S. Folder in question does have images.

Please guide.

Comment: I think it would be much easier to jump into understanding the problem if it was a minimal, complete example. The nature of the question seems to imply that scope is important, as well, so it would help if we had the whole picture.

Comment: @Mitch okay, will update the question on Monday.